# Magento 1.14.4.1: Not able to clean specific type of cache while using redis cache

Tags: cache, full-page-cache, redis, magento-1.14, block-cache

I have **redis** which is hosted separably. I need to clean specific type of cache (i.e. block_html) using a script. The problem is that whenever I update product it doesn't reflect on the front-end side until I clean the cache type `block_html`.

I need to use a script to clean the cache. The script is working fine in default cache, however It doesn't clean cache while redis the cache is active. However Whenever I clean cache from backend It works.

I have searched a lot but I just found commands like `redis-cli -h redis flushall` which flush the cache of entire Magento however, I just want to clean / flush the cache of a specific type.

Is there any command/script to achieve this?

Script:

```
<?php
require_once("app/Mage.php");

Mage::app('admin');
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$type = 'block_html';

Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Cache::getCacheInstance()->cleanType($type);

Mage::getConfig()->loadEventObservers('adminhtml');
Mage::app()->addEventArea('adminhtml');
//Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_cache_refresh_type', array('type' => $input->getArgument('type')));

Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_cache_refresh_type', array('type' => $type));
//Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType('block_html');
//$test->clean();
echo "success";
```

**Used Source:**

https://github.com/samm-git/cm_redis_tools

http://info2.magento.com/rs/magentosoftware/images/MagentoECG-UsingRedisasaCacheBackendinMagento.pdf

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once("app/Mage.php");

Mage::app('admin');
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$type = 'block_html';

Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Cache::getCacheInstance()->cleanType($type);
?>

try to execute above script in browser
```